# CMake Error: Target of type EXECUTABLE may not be linked into another target

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, cmakelists-options, cmake-language

I try to add GTest project to my solution. I have a project structure:
[my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVAtA.png)
I created Cryptograph and CryptographTests directories, after that created binTests and lib into CryptographTests.
I have a few CMakeLists.txt files:

- Cryptograph/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(Cryptograph)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)

add_executable(Cryptograph main.cpp modulArithmetics.cpp modulArithmetics.h Speakers.cpp Speakers.h Crypt.cpp Crypt.h LongArithmetic.cpp LongArithmetic.h Signs.cpp Signs.h)
target_link_libraries(Cryptograph OpenSSL::SSL)
```

- CryptographTests/CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(CryptographTest)

add_subdirectory(lib/googletest)
add_subdirectory(binTests)
```

- CryptographTests/lib/CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(CryptographGTest)

add_subdirectory(lib)
```

- CryptographTests/binTests/CMakeLists.txt:

```
include_directories(${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR})

add_executable(runCommonTests FirstTest.cpp)

target_link_libraries(runCommonTests gtest gtest_main)
target_link_libraries(runCommonTests Cryptograph)
```

- And CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(CryptographGlobal)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set (SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(cryptograph_samples ${SOURCE_FILES})

include_directories(Cryptograph)

add_subdirectory(Cryptograph)
add_subdirectory(CryptographTests)

target_link_libraries(cryptograph_samples Cryptograph)
```

After that i got errors:

```
CMake Error at CryptographTests/binTests/CMakeLists.txt:6 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "Cryptograph" of type EXECUTABLE may not be linked into another
  target.  One may link only to INTERFACE, OBJECT, STATIC or SHARED
  libraries, or to executables with the ENABLE_EXPORTS property set.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "Cryptograph" of type EXECUTABLE may not be linked into another
  target.  One may link only to INTERFACE, OBJECT, STATIC or SHARED
  libraries, or to executables with the ENABLE_EXPORTS property set.
```

Before this error I got error lool like can't connect to `Cryptograph.lib`, but after my changes errors also changed.

I try to add GTest project to my solution, but got the error.

Comment: Isn't the error fairly self explanatory? `Cryptograph` is an executable and you can't link to executables. You probably need to add a library then link both your executable and your tests to that library

Comment: You probably need to look at the CMakeLists.txt for `Cryptograph` to see what the proper target names are for library targets.

Comment: @artem21215 A better title for the question might include the error "Target of type EXECUTABLE may not be linked into another target". It would help others searching for similar errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition that your test executable needs access to your Cryptograph code somehow in order to test it is correct. However, linking an executable to another executable is not possible.

You'll want to make `Cryptograph` a **library** instead so that it compiles once and your executables (`cryptograph_samples` and `runCommonTests`) can link to it.

The library should also **not** have a `main()`. Otherwise it would clash with your executable's `main()` at link-time. So assuming `Cryptograph/main.cpp` contains a `main()` function, it should be excluded.

So, replace this line:

```
add_executable(Cryptograph main.cpp modulArithmetics.cpp ...)
```

with:

```
add_library(Cryptograph STATIC modulArithmetics.cpp ...) # no main.cpp
```

Using a `STATIC` library is one approach. You could also use a `SHARED` or `OBJECT` library. See the first reference link below for more on CMake library targets in general.

And if you need to execute `Cryptograph/main.cpp`, you can turn it into its own executable that links to `Cryptograph`, like so in `Cryptograph/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_executable(CryptographApp main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(CryptographApp Cryptograph)
```

**Resources**

- [CMake target types and composition](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html)
- [GoogleTest guide on incorporating into an existing CMake project](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/googletest/README.md#incorporating-into-an-existing-cmake-project) (~10 lines of code).
- [Integrating Google Test Into CMake Projects - by Matheus Gomes](https://matgomes.com/integrate-google-test-into-cmake/) illustrates multiple methods of bringing dependencies (like `googletest`) into CMake projects in general.